# How to deal with different length entities in a Keras DataGenerator?

Tags: keras, time-series, prediction

I'm solivng a prediction problem where I need to predict the demand of multiple articles based on their performance during the last 7 days. To get the most out of the data I am trying to implement a rolling window approach where I use 7 days as the training input (x) and the 8th day's performance as the training label (y).
As I am using Keras as a deep learning framework, how do I combine this rolling window approach with a custom data generator that feeds my network during training? The different articles have different data lengths (i.e. article A has 200 days worth of data, article B only has 10 days worth of data).
I implemented a version where I only use one sample per article but that drastically decreases the amount of data I have for training.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and the quick solution I came up with was iterate through the main data set, create an instance of `TimeseriesGenerator` for each of the subsets and feed it to the model. So in your case that would be: go through the collection of articles, instantiate `TimeseriesGenerator` for each article and feed the windowed samples to your model, ie.:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

# Set the training parameters
window_length = ...
ix0, ix1 = ...
batch_size = ...

for article in articles:
        # Insert your code to generate the article's features and targets
        x, y = ...

        model.fit_generator(TimeseriesGenerator(
                        x,
                        y,
                        window_length,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        start_index=ix0,
                        end_index=ix1
                ),
                steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil((x.shape[0] - ix0 - ix1 - window_length)/float(batch_size))),
                epochs=50,
                verbose=1
        )
```

Now depending on your dataset size and composition you can either:

- run a number of epochs per article
- or train one article per epoch, but for that you would need another loop.